# The constructor Geocoder(Map_Tracker, Locale) is undefined

Tags: java, android

when I extends MapFragment this error comes with cross sign: The constructor Geocoder(Map_Tracker, Locale) is undefined.Also I imported :import android.location.Geocoder;
I Made Fragment class and below code I deleted some code:

```
    public class Map_Tracker extends MapFragment {
    MapView myMapView;
    View rootView;
    public Map_Tracker() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_tracker, container, false);

         myMapView = (MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            updateWithNewLocation(location);

        return rootView;       
    }


        private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String latLongString;
            TextView myLocationText;
            myLocationText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            String addressString = "No Address Found";

            if(location != null)
            {
            // Update the map Location
                Double geoLat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
                Double geoLng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;

                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(geoLat.intValue(),geoLng.intValue());

                mapController.animateTo(point);
                Double lat = location.getLatitude();
                Double lng = location.getLongitude();
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(Map_Tracker.this, Locale.getDefault());

                try
                {
                    List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                }   
        }
    }
```

//Error on this line:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(Map_Tracker.this, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: You need to use `getActivity()` instead of `Map_Tracker.this`. Because in fragment as a `Context` you must use `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
```

instead of

```
   Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(Map_Tracker.this, Locale.getDefault());
```

In **Fragment**